# Using the <content> tag in a shadow DOM

Tags: html, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element, content-tag

I'm trying to use the shadow DOM without any framework that abstracts it, mostly in order to learn its intricacies. I am using the webcomponents.js polyfills, so it works cross-browser.

I've managed to create a custom element, and set its shadow DOM, but for some reason the `<content></content>` tag isn't transcluding the expected content.

I expect this example to render as

```
Shadow DOM
Hello world
More Shadow
```

But it renders as

```
Shadow DOM
More Shadow
```

What am I missing here?

```
<script src="webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

<test-component>
    <div>Hello world</div>
</test-component>

<template id="test-component">
    <div>Shadow DOM</div>
    <content></content>
    <div>More shadow</div>
</template>

<script>
    class TestComponent extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();

            var shadow = super.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

            var template = document.getElementById('test-component');
            var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
            shadow.appendChild(clone);
        }
    }

    customElements.define('test-component', TestComponent);
</script>
```

(The example is complete, and can be run as an entire HTML file, provided you have webcomponents-lite.min.js available, or can be run without the .js file in supported browsers)

Comment: The `content` element has been replaced by the `slot` element.

Comment: For an example of using the `slot` element and `slot` attribute instead, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/slot#Use_<slot>_in_<template>_to_make_a_doc_fragment_with_named_slots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in a comment above, you need to use the [`slot` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/slot) and [`slot` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-slot) instead.
Here’s exactly the same code as above, but implemented using the `slot` element and attribute:

```html
<test-component>
    <div slot=middle>Hello world</div>
</test-component>

<template id="test-component">
    <div>Shadow DOM</div>
    <slot name=middle></slot>
    <div>More shadow</div>
</template>

<script>
    class TestComponent extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();

            var shadow = super.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

            var template = document.getElementById('test-component');
            var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
            shadow.appendChild(clone);
        }
    }

    customElements.define('test-component', TestComponent);
</script>
```